# In how many ways can three men and five women (all distinguishable) line up for a group if the people at each end must be opposite sex?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I think it must look like this

W _ _ _ _ _ _ M and M _ _ _ _ _ _ W with the middle not mattering.

Would it be 5 ways for the first spot * 3 ways for the last spot * 6! and then the opposite for the man first 3*5*6! and add them together?

I think something sounds off.

Comment: Your answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be [$5.3.6!.2!$ ]  '2'indicates that the terminal positions can be taken by woman or a man so 2 ways.Rathsr than considering arrangenents separate for man and woman.