# How many ways can 5 men and 9 women line up for a photo if we require that the individuals at the end be of the same sex?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm not sure how to calculate this, but this is my guess:

$$(_5C_2 \times 2! \times 12!) + (_9C_2 \times 2! \times 12!)$$

or:

$$(_5P_2 \times 12!) + (_9P_2 \times 12!)$$

Choose two of the men to place at either end, then permute those two men, then calculate the combinations of the 12 others.

Choose two of women at either end, then permute those two women, then calculate the combinations of the the 12 others.

Finally, add them together.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1567029/in-how-many-ways-can-three-men-and-five-women-all-distinguishable-line-up-for?rq=1

Comment: Your answer is correct, the two expressions amount to the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To visualize it, it will go like this:

```
MMMMMWWWWWWWWW
```

that is 5 Men and 9 Woman, now your question indicates that same sex should be at the far end so we can divide the problem into 2 parts:

```
part 1: M MMM WWWWWWWWW M
part 2: W MMMMM WWWWWWW W
```

so how many ways are there for part 1: out of the 5 men we can use permutation of `5p2` and `12!` (use permutation for 5p2 because both M can reside on either left or right). For part 2 it's the same! `9p2` and `12!`

so your answer is correct with respect to:

$$(_5P_2 \times 12!) + (_9P_2 \times 12!)$$

(side note: you tagged this question as [probability] but it's not :-)  )